# Need help with ところ in 君の好きなところ

Tags: word-choice

So I'm trying to learn a song at the moment (good way to stay motivated c: ) and they use the phrase 「君の好きなところ」 which translates to "What I like about you", but I don't understand why the word ところ is used since it means "place" or "spot". Can anyone help out or give a more direct translation of the sentence so it makes a bit more sense please?

Much appreciated :)